# Why do I get different values in postgresql when using UCT values vs timezone names?

Tags: postgresql

If I run this query:

```
SELECT ('2021-11-02 08:00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'UCT') at TIME ZONE 'UCT+2';
```

It gives this result:

> ```
> 2021-11-02 10:00:00+00
> ```

Which seems correct to me...

However, my timezone data comes in string format, for example: "Africa/Johannesburg", which I know is on the UCT+2 timezone.

But running this query:

```
SELECT ('2021-11-02 08:00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'UCT') at TIME ZONE 'Africa/Johannesburg';
```

Gives this result:

> ```
> 2021-11-02 06:00:00+00
> ```

Which is the opposite of what I expect to happen. I know I can write code to convert the strings to a UCT value but I don't understand why the string values seems to do the opposite of using UCT values. Could someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: AFAIK there is no `UCT` time zone. Pretty sure you want `UTC`.

Comment: `UCT+2` (POSIX time zone) is somewhere in the Atlantic and is the same as `-02`. `Africa/Johannesburg` currently is `+02`, which would be `UCT-2` as POSIX time zone. Stick with the IANA names and avoid POSIX time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, there's lots to unpack here.

The main thing is that (to mis-quote Inigo Montoya) I do not think that `UTC+2` means what you think it means.

One important thing here is the precise format.

You say you get this result:

```
2021-11-02 06:00:00+00
```

But What I get is:

```
2021-11-02 06:00:00
```

And that's really important because what I get doesn't include that `+00`.  And that's because it's still `08:00` in the `+00` time zone.

The `AT TIME ZONE` syntax says something like "What would a local at this place see the time being at this specific UTC time?".  And someone in Johannesburg would see it as 10:00.  Someone in London (in winter time) would see it as 06:00.  But it's the same instant in time.

So the output of `AT TIME ZONE` doesn't usually have that time zone offset from UTC (`+00`) included in it.

Your conversions with two `AT TIME ZONE` clauses are redundant. Because it *knows* it's at that time zone, and hence what the UCT time is.   You'll get the same result with one `AT TIME ZONE` clause (try it).

The reason why you get different answers appears to be because PostgreSQL does not interpret `UCT+2` as the TimeZone that is 2 hours ahead of UCT.  It interprets that as you specifying a POSIX time zone definition, which could also include daylight savings time rules etc.

This page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html says PostgreSQL will accept time zones specified in 3 ways:

- Full name - e.g. 'Africa/Johannesburg'
- Abbreviation - e.g. 'SAST'
- Posix format, e.g. 'CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3' (This is, apparently, Paris)

Actually, it doesn't include the Posix format example, that's on this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-posix-timezone-specs.html

Basically, the posix format is a way of specifying the time zone rules.

Something like

`[abbreviation][offset][daylight savings abbrev][DST offset][dst rules]`

And so saying 'UCT+2' is probably "bad form" because you're trying to change the meaning of the abbreviation 'UTC' which has a standard usage.

You can verify that it isn't using the "UCT" part of your time zone to refer to the *actual* UCT time zone.  If you do this:

```
SELECT ('2021-11-02 08:00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'BOB')
```

PostgreSQL will say it doesn't recognise time zone "BOB".

But if you do

```
SELECT ('2021-11-02 08:00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'BOB+2')
```

It'll happily give you `06:00:00`.  In fact, if you like, you can stick (almost) anything in there instead of "UCT".  It doesn't get used in the calculation.

Note that the posix page I linked says

> POSIX time zone specifications are inadequate to deal with the
> complexity of real-world time zone history, but there are sometimes
> reasons to use them.

Finally, 'UCT' is perfectly valid but it's doing my head in. I've only seen it as 'UTC', so TIL.